# How do you defeat Sigdis Gauldurson?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

On the quest "Forbidden Legend", I can't figure out how to kill the eldest son of Archmage Gauldurson, Sigdis Gauldurson. He just keeps teleporting away, and there are three of him! Every time I kill one of them they just teleport and then there are three of them again! Please give me your advice if you have any idea on how do defeat Sigdis Gauldurson.

Answer (score 5):

This advice depends on whether you are a melee fighter/ranged/mage etc so YMMV. He is a very tough opponent at lower levels.

But when I started out to kill Sigdis for the first time, the thing I was looking was for to differentiate the real Sigdis and his illusions were :

1. Sigdis had his helmet's horns curled down (biggest giveaway IMO).
2. Sigdis had his health bar affected when he was hit like @Yves said
   already.
3. Sigdis was not surrounded by blue illusion adornments like his (oh
   well) illusions were.
4. The illusions die after one hit with your weapon bow/axe/spell etc

With time I got better at recognizing him.

If you are a melee class then the fourth point does you no good because he will simply teleport away. Instead look for the other three points and go for this guy with a vengeance. If you are an archer/mage types then you can deal damage from a distance almost hiding from him if you wish. In that case the fourth point applies.

You can still defeat him if you are a melee type, just takes a lot of patience going back and forth across the room (a lot IMO).

This is one battle where patience does pay out well. Just be patient. Do not make haste. And he can be brought down no matter your play style.

Answer (score 3):

There is only one real version of him; the other two are clones.

The easiest way to tell him from his clones is by checking the target's health before attacking. The real Gauldurson should already have some health missing from your attacks, whereas the clones will spawn with full health bars.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can figure out which is real. Besides, with my "Orcish Bow of Soul Devouring" (orcish bow with "soul trap" enchantment) and a lot of empty soul gems, I could fill the lot on clone after clone after clone. So there's a bright side to it. Thank you both, much appreciated.

Comment: The real one also has horns on his helmet, while the others do not.

Answer (score 2):

Stand in the circle where he gets out of his tomb and stand directly in front of the tomb...make sure you have a bow and a good amount of arrows. By standing in front of his tomb he can only spawn straight back parallel from where you'd be standing or on one of the two platforms in the middle of the room. Then just play the guessing game with the three of him it's pretty easy cause the illusions die from one arrow. Also stay crouched because right when he reappears your hidden and have a better chance of getting the first hit. I'm currently a low level and found this as the most effective way to kill him.

Answer (score 1):

If your weapon has a paralyze effect on it then it will bug out after 1 hit, he will appear as if hes dead and only the illusions will spawn.  Got stuck on this for over an hour because of this and then just switched out my weapon with an unenchanted weapon and killed him easily.

Answer (score 0):

when he teleports, hide behind a pillar and shoot him with bow if he dies in one hit its a decoy shoot another one if still die in one hit its a decoy shoot the last one (most likely it will not be last one) keep shooting real sigidis he will not move for a bit unless it took you a long time to kill decoys repeat that over and over again until he's dead

Answer (score 0):

I found it very helpful as a full melee-er to just pick up a bow, gather some arrows and shoot him from a distance. If you're too low of a level and you're struggling to take him down, this is a very easy way. Bear in mind that you take a bloody eternity to take him down. If you run out of arrows, just let the fake Sigdis' shoot at you but don't let them hit you and pick up the arrows!

Answer (score -2):

Just keep attacking all one of him, he will eventually die.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can figure out which is real. Besides, with my "Orcish Bow of Soul Devouring" (orcish bow with "soul trap" enchantment) and a lot of empty soul gems, I could fill the lot on clone after clone after clone. So there's a bright side to it. Thank you both, much appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

I'm a different player from this answer up here.. just posting here since someone brought up Sigdis showing dead and only 2 clones showing. 
Well, if this happens to you, like it happened to him and also to me, what I did was I walked to the "dead" Sigdis and I shouted him off the circle.. immediately Sigdis got up and I ran to him and finished him.

Comment: Can you clarify your answer, and maybe get rid of information irrelevant to the question?

Answer (score -6):

Press <kbd>~</kbd>, then type [`tgm`](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console#Toggle_Commands) and you're done.

Comment: Saying "enable godmode" doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @dramerius To avoid downvotes, provide more details on your answer. e.g. explain what`tgm` does, and that one might want to disable it afterwards to not play the whole game in 'god mode'.